# Silent 'read' in dash

Tags: shell

I like making POSIX compliant shell scripts. However, one feature that I miss from bash is the builtin "read -s", which supresses the echoing, ideal for password prompts. Is there a similar feature in dash?

Comment: Are you okay with using `stty`?

Comment: To be clear: You can find the source to the dash implementation of `read` at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/miscbltin.c#n116. There is no equivalent to the `-s` argument, which means you need to achieve that goal another way... like with `stty`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sure